# send file size with socket

Tags: linux, sockets

How send a long through a socket? and How to receive it?

Server:

```
                long size;

                f = fopen("file.txt","r");;

                fseek(f,0,SEEK_END);

                size = ftell(f);

                rewind(f);

                printf("Size: %ld Bytes\n",size);

                /* send "size" with send method */

                send(socket,???,???,0);
```

Client:

```
                long size;

                recv(socket,???,???,0);
```

Thanks to all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the same endianness and `sizeof(long)` on both sides of the connection:

```
send(socket, &size, sizeof size, 0);
```

and:

```
recv(socket, &size, sizeof size, 0);
```

Those assumptions may not be correct, though, so be careful.

Comment: Thanks! Can I use htons(size) on the server and ntons(size) on the client for greater safety?

Comment: Well, you should use `htonl` and `ntohl` (or maybe a 64-bit version) since they're `long` not `short` variables, but yes, that's the idea.

Comment: If I don't know the software architecture of server and client, what is the best choice for store the size of the file?

Comment: Dictate the size in the protocol you are implementing. If you need to handle files > 4GB, then use a 64-bit data type (`unsigned __int64`, `uint64_t`, etc), otherwise use a 32-bit data type instead (`unsigned int`, `int32_t`, etc).